# Class.forName(“com.mysql.jdbc.Driver”) does not work on Raspberry Pi

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, classnotfoundexception

this code:

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

leads to an

> ClassNotFoundException

on raspberry Pi. although my Classpath is correct

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ echo $CLASSPATH
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar
```

on Windows it just works fine!
any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I also tried to start my Application with

> java -cp /usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar -jar myApp.jar

thanks
florian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `-jar`, which makes the `-cp` part irrelevant. From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html):

> When you use the -jar option, the specified JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other class path settings are ignored.

Either [add ClassPath entries in your jar manifest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html), or add the MySQL connector jar file to an extension directory (e.g. `jre/lib/ext`). Using the manifest is the cleanest approach though.

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the `MySql-Connector.jar` in `apache tomcat's lib folder` and then `remove the jar` in `project's lib folder` and then, run the project.

What did you put exactly in lib, `jre/lib or jre/lib/ext?` Was it the jar `mysql-connector-java-5.1.5-bin.jar` or something else (like a directory)?

By the way, I wouldn't put it in lib, `jre/lib or jre/lib/ext`, there are other ways to add a jar to the classpath. You can do that by adding it explicitly the `CLASSPATH` environment variable. Or you can use the `-cp` option of java.

Comment: Err this is related to the original question exactly how? OP does not mention Tomcat nor putting something inside JRE install path?